# Laravel 5 Tinker eval() error

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to test my model relations using tinker but they're all giving errors
This is the code I'm trying

```
$event = \App\Event::all();
```

This is the error

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method App\Event::all() in
>   D:\Sites\nightshift2015\vendor\psy\psy

I have tried without the first \ but it's giving the same error

```
$event = App\Event::all();
```

This is my Event class

```
<?php namespace App;

class Event {

    public function exhibitors() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Exhibitor');
    }

    public function conference() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Conference');
    }

}
```

Comment: It looks like it found your class okay.  Can you please post the contents of your `App\Event` class?

Comment: added the class to the question, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that’s your event class, then it’s not extending Laravel’s base `Model` class, therefore hasn’t inherited any of its methods.

Fix it by changing it to this:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Event extends Model {
```

Comment: Aha! Stupid mistake of me. Thank you!

Comment: If you create your models with artisan, this will be handled for you `php artisan make:model ModelName`